# Tailwind 3.3.2 - module is not defined

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, es6-modules, commonjs

I am stuck on a tutorial which is incorporating Tailwind, which in this case is tailwind 3.3.2.

Per the tutorial, I am supposed to open a file called tailwind.config.js and paste the below code from https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

I immediately get the red squiggly line under "module", with an error that reads as follows:

[image]

What did I do wrong? The tutorial did not encounter this error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Seems like the code itself is correct. The message you are seeing in your IDE seems to be coming from ESLint, with regards to the [`no-undef` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-undef). To resolve the error, consider letting ESLint know that this file is meant to be used in the environment of Node.js by adding `/*eslint-env node*/` as per the [the documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-undef#nodejs).

Comment: Well, I used your suggestion and the error is gone.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you haven't figured it out, convert `module.exports` to `export default`. That's should fix your issue

Answer (score 1):

In my own case, i wanted to use flowbite with vite and react so, changing the module.exports to export default will only cause required not defined again.

What i did was to add /*eslint-env node*/ to the tailwind.config.js file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).